# Merge an array of hashes in Ruby and count the same key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some data in this format

```
[{
    "_id" => "20",
    "value" => 1
}, {
    "_id" => "19",
    "value" => 1
}, {
    "_id" => nil,
    "value" => 8
}, {
    "_id" => "27",
    "value" => 1
}, {
    "_id" => "25",
    "value" => 3
}, {
    "_id" => "28",
    "value" => 1
}]
```

I want to merge the same values with "_id" key and sum the "value" values.

Desire output

```
[{
    "_id" => "20",
    "value" => 1
}, {
    "_id" => "19",
    "value" => 2
}, {
    "_id" => nil,
    "value" => 8
}, ...]
```

There is an elegant way to do this?

I have tried with two loops but I think that is not the best way to do it.

Comment: Please read "[ask]", the linked pages,  and "[mcve]". What have you tried? We need to see the minimum code demonstrating the problem, along with the absolute minimum input data also. Without that it looks like you want us to do your work. “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)” is applicable too.

Comment: Don't you need to update "Example of output"? You might call that "Expected output" or "Desired output".

Comment: Your output still doesn't match your input (`"_id => "19"`). Also, please give the full expected output (no `...`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with most things in Ruby, a trip to the [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html) documentation turns up the [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) method which can help group things together by some arbitrary criteria. Combine that with something that does the sums and you get this:

```
v.group_by do |e|
  e['_id']
end.map do |id, list|
  {
    '_id' => id,
    'value' => list.inject(0) { |sum, e| sum + e['value'] }
  }
end

# => [{"_id"=>"20", "value"=>1}, {"_id"=>"19", "value"=>2}, {"_id"=>nil, "value"=>28},
#     {"_id"=>"27", "value"=>1}, {"_id"=>"25", "value"=>3}, {"_id"=>"28", "value"=>1},
#     {"_id"=>"23", "value"=>1}, {"_id"=>"16", "value"=>1}, {"_id"=>"18", "value"=>2},
#     {"_id"=>"22", "value"=>2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [{ "_id" => "20", "value" => 1 },
       { "_id" => "19", "value" => 1 },
       { "_id" =>  nil, "value" => 8 },
       { "_id" => "20", "value" => 1 },
       { "_id" => "25", "value" => 3 },
       { "_id" => "19", "value" => 1 },
      ]

h = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |g,h| h[g["_id"]] += g["value"] }
  #=> {"20"=>2, "19"=>2, nil=>8, "25"=>3}
```

If you instead want to return an array of hashes with unique values for `"_id"` and the values of `"value"` updated, you could first compute `h` above, then

```
arr.uniq { |g| g["_id"] }.map { |g| g.update("_id"=>h[g["_id"]]) }
  #=> [{"_id"=>"20", "value"=>2}, {"_id"=>" 19", "value"=>2},
  #    {"_id"=>nil, "value"=>8}, {"_id"=>"25", "value"=>3}]
```

This uses the methods [Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) with a block, [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and  [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`).

Alternatively, you could write the following.

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
  h.update(g["_id"]=>g) { |_,o,n| o.merge("value"=>o["value"]+n["value"]) } }.values
  #=> [{"_id"=>"20", "value"=>2}, {"_id"=>" 19", "value"=>2},
  #    {"_id"=>nil, "value"=>8}, {"_id"=>"25", "value"=>3}]
```

Again, I've used `Hash#update`, but this time I have employed a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See also [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) and [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge). Note that, as arguments, `(k=>v)` is shorthand for `({ k=>v })`.